# El método FileOutputStream en spring boot no crea ningun archivo en el directorio

Tags: java, spring-boot

desde ya hace varias horas estoy intentando poder subir un archivo al servidor a partir de un dato base64, pero a pesar de que no marca error y de que todo está lo hace bien, no me hace nada, localmente me trabaja súper, pero lo subo al servidor y deja de funcionar. Adjunto imagen (soy nuevo en la plataforma) [image: código que estoy manejando]

Comment: ¿Puedes sustituir la imagen por texto? Te recomiendo completar el [tour] para entender [ask]. Las imágenes no compilan y no podemos copiar y pegar el código para poder modificarlo en una respuesta

Comment: Por otro lado, no cierras el stream, ¿Has probado `var fos = new FileOutputStream(directory); fos.write(imageByte); fos.close();`?

Comment: @PabloLozano lo hice como lo sugeriste y pasa el mismo error, si bien funciona correctamente localmente no funciona cuando subo al servidor, nose que configuración cambia cuando se sube al servidor :(